# whats the best way to store a single object in core data for a user

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have a simple iPhone app which accesses some remote data on start-up then asks the user to select one of the options chosen, but this happens each time the app starts, and I want the app to remember that choice for next time around, how can I persist this object using Core Data?

Im very new to Core Data, and I figure its something to do with adding an object to the `NSManagedObjectContext` but im not sure if there is a way to store one object against a key or something so that I can check if its been chosen before quickly to avoid doing the remote call...

**EDIT**

Ok, seems like `NSUserDefaults` is the way to go here, but I have a small issue, my custom class is extends `NSManagedObject` which I hear is a bit tough to store an instance of in NSUserDefaults, so I wrote a little converter that takes each property of the class and puts it in NSUserDefaults seperatly under different keys.

like so:

```
-(void)saveDeviceForUser:(Device*) device
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSData *encodedActive = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:device.active];
    [defaults setObject:encodedActive forKey:@"UsersDevice_Active"];

    //and so on for each property of the Device object
}
```

then I retrieve my object in a similar fashion:

```
-(Device*)loadDeviceForUser
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSData *encodedActive = [defaults objectForKey: @"UsersDevice_Active"];
    NSNumber* unarchivedActive = (NSNumber*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: encodedActive];

    Device *d = [[Device alloc] init];
    d.active = unarchivedActive;

    return d;
}
```

But, when I get to the line above of `d.active = unarchivedActive` I get an error:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Device setActive:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xac0be10'**

My class properties are setup using @dynamic and not @synthesize, so do I have to implement the setters and getters in order for this to work? Will that upset Core Data in any way?

I hope that makes sense

Cheers,
Mark

Comment: You have NSNumber* unarchivedActive, it might need to be NSNumber *unarchivedActive

Comment: bingo!! it turns out there were a lot of issues at hand here, and it was late... stupid copy and paste errors!! thanks for the help all sorted now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would store the object using [NSUserDefaults](http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/20/using_nsuserdefaults/)

When storing a custom object, you must [archive](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Tasks/codingobjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000948-BCIHBJDE) it correctly

Comment: Another example is to use a custom [NSMutableDictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609305/updating-changing-settings-plist-files-with-new-versions-of-an-app)

Comment: **@dylan**, thanks Ill give that a go and let you know, but quick question, are you saying that to store an object in NSUserDefaults I need to define how it gets serialised? **@tadman** I need persist the object over application runs

Comment: To store things in `NSUserDefaults` they need to be broken down into "standard" objects, strings, numbers, dates, dictionaries, arrays, etc. Or you need to turn it into binary data.  Storing it as standard objects is easier.

Comment: thanks so much for the help so far, I have updated the question please take a look for me?

Comment: Ok, so all sorted now, turns out the NSUserDefaults is very easy to use and my mistake was a noobie error :)